# Sliding menu (library) always fullscreen

Tags: android, layout, menu

I'm trying to implement the [sliding menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my app. My problem now is that I don't seem to be able to control the width of the menu. It is always fullscreen.

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this?

Here is the code I've been playing with.

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
menu.setBehindWidth(10);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those that happen to stumble upon this question, in search of how to resolve it - I was able to resolve my issue by using the following code in my `onCreate` method.

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenuWidth);
sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenuOffset);
sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

<dimen name="slidingmenuWidth">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="slidingmenuOffset">60dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the commit logs read `Only behind width not working now [jfeinstein10]`. Probably its broken.

What you CAN do is to go to biggest component containing everything and set `android:minWidth` on it. After a cursory look it seems like it might be `menu_frame.xml`. But you might want to check a few things.

Comment: I'll play with the code and see if I can get it working. Thanks for doing that research!